# get Ubuntu Linux's grep to only get emails from a certain domain in a file?

Tags: regex, email, ubuntu, grep

I'm sifting through a .asc file trying to get all the instances of emails registered at a certain domain, say 'abc.def' just as an example.
I try this:

```
grep -o ,*@abc.def somefile.asc
```

which does nothing, although I know for a fact that such emails exist in the file.

Is something wrong with my regular expression? Keep in mind that the file is essentially a csv file, hence the comma at the front. I've tried escaping it with \ but still no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -o ,*@abc.def somefile.asc
```

This will find **zero** or more commas followed by `@abc` then **any character** (since dot is unescaped) and then `def` in any line.

What you probably want is this:

```
grep -oE '[^[:blank:]@,]+@abc\.def' somefile.asc
```

- `[^[:blank:]@,]+`: Uses a negated bracket expression to match any character that is not white-space and `@` and `@`
- `@`: Match literal `@`
- `abc\.def`: Match literal text `abc.def` (note how dot must be escaped to match literal `.`)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I even simplified it to '[^[:blank:],]+@abc.def'

Comment: Yes but dot matches any character in regex